# PL/SQL CPU performance tuning

Tags: performance, plsql

I have PL/SQL program that after making some changes has gone from a run-time of 30 mins to 3 hours, we have been unable to identify how to improve performance.
The program origiannly output a csv file for use in excel. The progam has now been changed to output XML for use in excel.
So there have been no code changes in respect of SQL or database reads.
The relevant code addtions are procedure picked up from an associated package that builds clobs which are then output to the file on a regular basis, so as too avoid excess memory usage. The number of utl_file.put_line usages is similar in both versions of the program.

An example of code used to build the CLOB is

```
PROCEDURE cell_write(p_xml_body  IN OUT NOCOPY CLOB,
                     p_data_type IN            VARCHAR2 := 'String',
                     p_style_id  IN            VARCHAR2 := NULL,
                     p_merge     IN            VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
                     p_formula   IN            VARCHAR2 := NULL,
                     p_line_feed IN            BOOLEAN  := TRUE,
                     p_content   IN            VARCHAR2) IS     
   v_line_feed   VARCHAR2(01) ;                    
BEGIN
  IF p_line_feed 
  THEN 
      v_line_feed := chr(10) ;
  ELSE 
      v_line_feed := ' ' ;
  END IF ;  
  p_xml_body := p_xml_body || '    <Cell';
  IF p_merge IS NULL 
  THEN 
      p_xml_body := p_xml_body ;
  ELSE 
      p_xml_body := p_xml_body || ' ss:MergeAcross="' || p_merge || '"' ;
  END IF ; 
  IF p_style_id IS NULL 
  THEN 
      p_xml_body := p_xml_body ;
  ELSE 
      p_xml_body := p_xml_body || ' ss:StyleID="'||p_style_id||'"' ;
  END IF;
  IF p_formula IS NULL
  THEN 
      p_xml_body := p_xml_body ;
  ELSE 
      p_xml_body := p_xml_body || ' ss:Formula="'||p_formula||'"' ;
  END IF;
  p_xml_body := p_xml_body || '><Data ss:Type="'||p_data_type||'">' ||                   P_content || '</Data></Cell>' || v_line_feed;
END cell_write;
```

The code to write output is

```
PROCEDURE write_file(p_filename    IN VARCHAR2,
                     p_dir         IN VARCHAR2,
                     p_file_handle IN utl_file.file_type,
                     p_clob        IN CLOB)
  IS

c_amount CONSTANT BINARY_INTEGER := 32767;
l_buffer   VARCHAR2(32767);
l_chr10    PLS_INTEGER;
l_cloblen  PLS_INTEGER;
l_fhandler utl_file.file_type;
l_pos      PLS_INTEGER := 1;

BEGIN

l_cloblen  := dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob);

WHILE l_pos < l_cloblen
LOOP
  l_buffer := dbms_lob.substr(p_clob, c_amount, l_pos);
  EXIT WHEN l_buffer IS NULL;
  l_chr10 := instr(l_buffer, chr(10), -1);

  IF l_chr10 != 0 THEN
    l_buffer := substr(l_buffer, 1, l_chr10 - 1);
  END IF;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Buffer Length ' || LENGTH(l_buffer)) ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_buffer) ;
  utl_file.put_line(p_file_handle, l_buffer, TRUE);
  l_pos := l_pos + least(length(l_buffer) + 1, c_amount);
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Buffer Length ' || LENGTH(l_buffer)) ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_buffer) ; 
  IF utl_file.is_open(l_fhandler) THEN
    utl_file.fclose(l_fhandler);
  END IF;
  RAISE;
 END;
```

and a sample call is

```
pk_create_excel_workbook.cell_write(p_xml_body    =>v_clob_term,
                                    p_line_feed   => FALSE,
                                    p_data_type   =>'Number',
                                    p_style_id    =>'s94',
                                    p_content     =>w_totemployeecontribT);
```

The procedure cell_write is called about 100 times per output line and there about 30,000 output lines. So output lines are typically 8000 to 10000 bytes long.

We expected a modest increase in runtime but not the massive jump that has occurred. What have I overlooked?

Comment: You've overlooked profiling. Please see [PL/SQL Hierarchical Profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_profiler.htm).

Comment: Even plain old `dbms_profiler`, for all its limitations, would indicate which line is taking the time, without the need to access the server. I'd guess it's the multiple concatenations in `cell_write` (which can probably be combined using `case` statements), or else either reading the clob or writing to the file. (I'm puzzled by all those `p_xml_body := p_xml_body;` lines too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be the multiple concatenations in `cell_write`. (Profiling will confirm.)

Ideally you would use the supplied XML interface tools rather than concatenating tags manually like this, but anyway as a quick fix I would try something like this (untested):

```
procedure cell_write
    ( p_xml_body  in out nocopy clob
    , p_data_type in varchar2 := 'String'
    , p_style_id  in varchar2 := null
    , p_merge     in varchar2 := null
    , p_formula   in varchar2 := null
    , p_line_feed in boolean := true
    , p_content   in varchar2 )
is
    k_line_feed constant varchar2(1) := case when p_line_feed then chr(10) else ' ' end;
begin
    p_xml_body := p_xml_body ||
        '    <Cell' ||
        case when p_merge is not null then ' ss:MergeAcross="' || p_merge || '"' end ||
        case when p_style_id is not null then ' ss:StyleID="' || p_style_id || '"' end ||
        case when p_formula is not null then ' ss:Formula="' || p_formula || '"' end ||
        '><Data ss:Type="' || p_data_type || '">' || p_content || '</Data></Cell>' ||
        k_line_feed;
end cell_write;
```

Comment: Thanks for comments, I was unfamiliar with using DBMS profiling, I have now learnt and used and got the program back down to 30 mins. It would seem that constantly concatenating onto a CLOB is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I've been using for a long time now, is to work with temporary `CLOBs` using a `varchar2` stateful `PL/SQL` variable as a buffer before performing `CLOB` appends. And I created a simple API around the core `DBMS_LOB` to allow me to write to more than one `CLOB` at any time, alternating between them if necessary. You can take a look at it, maybe you can achieve an even better performance:

https://github.com/GeraldoViana/nksg/blob/master/src/nksg_tempclob.pks
https://github.com/GeraldoViana/nksg/blob/master/src/nksg_tempclob.pkb